# finding rotation of a 3D basis relative to another coordination basis

Tags: geometry, rotation, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

consider we have a coordination system (i,j,k) its origin at (0,0,0)
now i create another coordination system inside the original space with three vectors(t,u,v) from original space.
what is the rotation (yaw,pitch,roll) of this new basis relative to the original space ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the origin does not change in the new basis, then it's a linear transformation, otherwise it's an affine transformation matrix, which combines the rotation and translation. In both cases, you can determine the transformation matrices, with which the rotation (yaw,pitch,roll) can be easily determined. See [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html) for more information. Also, just a friendly reminder, math.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask this kind of questions.